# Asp.net Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Tags: asp.net, mysql, memory, repeater, protected

After being plagued over a year with the dredded "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt", I have finally found a fix on it!

Background: asp.net 4.0. Windows server 2003. Using MySQL database.

I used to randomly get this issue on a few pages, and coincidently, the pages had an asp.net repeater on it. I tried all sorts of recommendations, but they simply didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using system.data.odbc , with an odbc driver installed for all of my asp.net pages to interact with the database. Here comes the fix... I instead downloaded MySQL.data.dll, and used this library for my db. Voila! Problem fixed.

Comment: MySQL.data.dll can be downloaded at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads - put the dll in the bin folder and simply reference the dll instead of the system.data.odbc